# Trying to figure out why (or whether) app pool is recycling in IIS 8.5 / Windows 2012 R2

Tags: iis, iis-8, application-pool

We've recently moved an application from IIS on Windows 2008 32-bit to IIS on Windows 2012 R2 64-bit.

This app loads a .NET class library from the GAC that we wrote, and in that library some things happen only once, when the app is first loaded. We get an email from the library when this event happens.

In the past, if we saw one of these emails, we knew that the app pool was recycled, or IIS crashed, or the server itself crashed.

In the new environment, with Windows 2012, we are seeing these emails generated once or twice a day, with no event log entry indicating anything: no app pool recycle, no crashes, nothing. I've re-verified that we have no app pool recycling turned on for the app pool in IIS. The app pool timeout recycle is the default 20 minutes, but this app pool gets high traffic and would never have zero traffic for 10 seconds let alone 20 minutes... and again, nothing in event log.

I've verified that all of the "record event log entry" settings are set to True for this app pool, so if the app pool was recycled, it seems that we should be seeing it in the event log.

My only theories at this point are:

1. In IIS 8.5, app pools might reload .NET libraries even without an app pool recycle? If so, does anyone have more information on this phenomenon?
2. The app pool is recycling, but none of the event log recording settings are the right one to catch the reason why?

What else can we try to find out why it's happening?

**UPDATE**

I've now run this command:

`ps w3wp | select ProcessName, Id, StartTime | ft -AutoSize`

And determined that the app pool in question has a start time a day earlier than the latest emailed "event" mentioned above, which seems to imply the app pool did *not* recycle, and therefore we would now be leaning towards theory #1 above: our library was reloaded, but not the app pool itself.